# Как удалить из строки цифры, стоящие в середине, начале или конце слова?

Tags: java

Хочу сделать метод, который будет заменять цифры 3,4,6, стоящие в начале, середине или в конце слова, на буквы "з", "ч", "б" соответственно, а остальные цифры просто удалять. Например: строку *Я не сп5ал 20 4асов7* он будет менять на *Я не спал 20 часов*.

Вот что у меня есть на данный момент:

```
static private StringBuilder checkWrongLetters(StringBuilder inputText) {
    StringBuilder outputText = inputText;
    Character theFirstSymbol = outputText.charAt(0);
    Character theSecondSymbol = outputText.charAt(1);
    Character theLastSymbol = outputText.charAt(outputText.length()-1);
    Character penultimateSymbol = outputText.charAt(outputText.length()-2);

    //Обработка первого символа
    switch (Character.getNumericValue(theFirstSymbol)) {
        case 4:
            outputText.setCharAt(0, 'ч');
            break;
        case 6:
            outputText.setCharAt(0, 'б');
            break;
        case 3:
            outputText.setCharAt(0, 'з');
            break;
        default:
            if (theFirstSymbol.isDigit(theFirstSymbol) && !theSecondSymbol.isDigit(theSecondSymbol)){
                outputText.deleteCharAt(0);
            }
    }
    //Обработка последнего символа
    switch (Character.getNumericValue(theLastSymbol)) {
        case 4:
            outputText.setCharAt(outputText.length()-1, 'ч');
            break;
        case 6:
            outputText.setCharAt(outputText.length()-1, 'б');
            break;
        case 3:
            outputText.setCharAt(outputText.length()-1, 'з');
            break;
        default:
            if (theLastSymbol.isDigit(theLastSymbol) && !penultimateSymbol.isDigit(penultimateSymbol)) {
                outputText.deleteCharAt(outputText.length() - 1);
            }
    }
    //Обработка символов от второго до предпоследнего
    for (int i = 1; i < outputText.length() - 1; i++) {
        Character symbol = outputText.charAt(i);
        Character previousSymbol = outputText.charAt(i - 1);
        Character nextSymbol = outputText.charAt(i + 1);

        while (symbol.isDigit(symbol)) {

            if (symbol.isDigit(symbol) &&
                    (!nextSymbol.isDigit(nextSymbol) || !previousSymbol.isDigit(previousSymbol))) {

                switch (Character.getNumericValue(symbol)) {
                    case 4:
                        outputText.setCharAt(i, 'ч');
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        outputText.setCharAt(i, 'б');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        outputText.setCharAt(i, 'з');
                        break;
                    default:
                        outputText.deleteCharAt(i);
                }

                i--;
                symbol = outputText.charAt(i);
                nextSymbol = outputText.charAt(i+1);

            } else {
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return outputText;
}
```

Пока метод заменяет все цифры 3,4,6, а не только те, что стоят в начале, середине и конце слова, но вопрос не в этом.

Собственно, сама проблема: в случае, когда рассматриваем первый символ строки и пытаемся проверить символ, стоящий перед ним, мы выходим за пределы строки и получаем `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, то же самое и с последним символом когда проверяем символ, стоящий за ним. Поэтому мне пришлось рассмотреть первый и последний символ в отдельных случаях, а в цикле проверять символы со второго до предпоследнего. Знаю, что это неправильно, и наверняка есть способ проверить все символы с помощью одного только цикла, тем самым уменьшив количество строк кода раза в три.

Есть предположение, что нужно использовать обработку исключений, но как это реализовать конкретно в этом случае, в силу своей неопытности, сообразить не могу. Или же нужно пересмотреть весь метод в целом?

Нуждаюсь в ваших советах.

Comment: Не пробовали использовать RegEx для этих целей?

Comment: Опять же в силу своей неопытности, с ними не сталкивался. Стоит изучить и применить их в данной задаче?

Comment: __Пока метод заменяет все цифры 3,4,6, а не только те, что стоят в начале, середине и конце слова__
Так это и получаются все! Или вы странно описали вашу цель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит использовать RegExp.

Полезные ссылки по теме:

- [Регулярные выражения на Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [java.util.regex.Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
- [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Вот возможное решение:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Replacer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*$");
        final String input = "Я не сп5ал 20 4асов7";
        final String[] words = input.split("[\\s]");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

        final StringBuilder clearWorlds = new StringBuilder();
        for (final String word : words) {
            final Matcher matcher = numberPattern.matcher(word);
            final boolean isNumber = matcher.find();
            if (isNumber) {
                clearWorlds.append(word);
            } else {
                final String clearWord = word.replaceAll("3", "з")
                        .replaceAll("4", "ч")
                        .replaceAll("6", "б")
                        .replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
                clearWorlds.append(clearWord);
            }
            clearWorlds.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(clearWorlds);
    }
}
```